# React Native listen to Websocket to send Push Notifications?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, websocket, push-notification

I have an existing server that allows websocket connections, and publishes certain messages.

I'd like to start some kind of background task that can listen in on these messages and send a push notification to the user (even when the app is in the background).

What's the best way to do this? I've found react-native-push-notification for sending local push notifications; but so far I haven't really found anything that will let me keep a background process running. Looks like https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html might be promising.

Answer (score 2):

So, after some research, I've realized this is just imply something you don't do.

You instead have to have your app register with Google's GCM Servers (in the case of android). You get back a token. You then send that token along to your server. When you want to push a notification, your server has to send that token along with the notification data to the GCM Servers.

Comment: And now it's all out Firebase since GCM is deprecated.

Comment: @Noah Did you end up solving this problem?

Comment: Yeah. You can't do what I was trying to do. If you think about it, every app on your phone having a websocket open in the background would get expensive. So they don't allow it. Instead, they basically have on push socket open (GCM), and you need to set up a service that listens to your websocket and publishes to GCM.